# Specflow feature file.cs is not generating

Tags: selenium, specflow

Generation error: Unable to load plugin assembly:

> C...\packages\Baseclass.Contrib.SpecFlow.Selenium.NUnit.1.3.1\tools\Baseclass.Contrib.SpecFlow.Selenium.NUnit.SpecFlowPlugin.dll.

-> Could not load file or assembly

> 'file:///C:...\packages\Baseclass.Contrib.SpecFlow.Selenium.NUnit.1.3.1\tools\Baseclass.Contrib.SpecFlow.Selenium.NUnit.SpecFlowPlugin.dll'
>   or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x80131515)

=> An attempt was made to load an assembly from a network location which
   would have caused the assembly to be sandboxed in previous versions
   of the .NET Framework. This release of the .NET Framework does not
   enable CAS policy by default, so this load may be dangerous. If this
   load is not intended to sandbox the assembly, please enable the
   loadFromRemoteSources switch.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the SpecFlow-Selenium-Nunit package through NuGet? Messages like this occur when you download and install plugins manually without enabling the load of resources from external sources. You can enable it by setting the [loadFromRemoteSources property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee890038(v=vs.110).aspx) in your project options.